# How do I return a promise from batch.commit() scheduled function in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

This is my first time writing a scheduled function in Firebase. I'm trying to read sports data from a third party API and place that data into Firestore. I first built the function as a regular cloud function, verified that it writes to the database using batch, and then attempted to convert to a scheduled function that I want to run every 2 hours. Unfortunately, the data is not writing to Firestore and I am also getting the following error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value.

```
exports.getTodaysNCAABGames = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 hours').onRun((context) => {

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com/games',
    qs: {status: 'in progress', odds: 'any', league: 'NCAAB'},
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'sportspage-feeds.p.rapidapi.com',
      useQueryString: true
    }
  };

  requesting(options, function (error, res, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const batch = db.batch();
    const bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
    const essentialResultsData = getNCAABEventData(bodyParsed.results);

    const ncaaRef = db.collection('ncaab');
    essentialResultsData.forEach(result => {
      batch.create(ncaaRef.doc(result.gameId), result);
    });
    return batch.commit();
  });
});

function getNCAABEventData(results) {
  const essentialEventData = [];
  results.forEach((result) => {
    const gameId = result.gameId.toString();
    const status = result.status;
    const oddsObject = result.odds;
    const scoreboard = result.scoreboard;
    const teams = result.teams;

    const resultData = {
      gameId: gameId,
      status: status,
      odds: oddsObject,
      scoreboard: scoreboard,
      teams: teams
    };

    essentialEventData.push(resultData);
  });
  return essentialEventData;
}
```

I guess that the `batch.create` returns a promise, but I thought with `return batch.commit()`, I would be returning all promises associated with each batch.create call.

I feel close but I'm just missing something very simple. Any and all help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return batch.commit()` does return a single promise, but it doesn't return a promise from the top level of the entire function.  It's returning the promise from inside the callback function that you passed to `requesting`.  That's not going to be propagated out of the top level function.

I suggest looking into an alternative for `requesting` that lets you work with promises instead of callbacks.  A popular option is axios.  Whatever you use, it should return a promise with the result of the query and let you chain the results in a form like this:

```
return request(...)
.then(result => {
    // work with the result to add data to Firestore
    return batch.commit()
})
```